# Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ singular matrix. Describe how to construct...

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, singularity

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ singular matrix. Describe how to construct an $n\times n$ non zero matrix such that $AB = 0$.

I'm not sure how to approach this correctly. I think I am supposed to use the idea that $A$ is not invertible, which tells me that the columns of $A$ are linearly dependent and $A$ has less than $n$ pivots.

How can I use this information to construct $B$?

Comment: For an additional challenge, construct a nonzero $B$ with $AB=0$ **and** $BA=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide:

- Start by finding a non-zero $x$ such that $Ax=0$ (explain why you can find it).
- Think of how to make good use of the $x$ that you find to construct $B$.

Comment: Since A is not invertible , that means that $Ax = 0$ doesn't have the trivial solution as the ONLY solution, so that implies that there MUST be a non zero $x$ which makes $Ax = 0$ true. But i think i need another hint on how to actually construct $B$ . Is it possible to put $x$ in a zero n x n matrix?

Comment: Can you try to evaluate $A \begin{bmatrix} x & \ldots &  x \end{bmatrix}$ ? what about $A \begin{bmatrix} 2x & 3x &  \ldots &  (n+1)x \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: so $[x ... x]$ is the matrix B then?

Comment: $B$ is clearly not unique. If you verified that it works then it is a candidate.

Comment: $$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2\\ 1 & 2 
\end{pmatrix} * 
 \begin{pmatrix} -2 & -2\\ 1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix} = 0

$$ the equation above represents $Ax = 0$... it seems to work

Comment: yup, it should work. note that we have $A \begin{bmatrix} x & \ldots & x \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix} Ax & \ldots & Ax \end{bmatrix} $